# Reference manager incompatibility

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

How do I deal with reference manager incompatibilities? I'm using CITAVI and it's only suitable (apparently) for the regular Os's. Is there a way to get rid of all these issues once and for all or every case deserves special attention?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm uncertain as to what you are asking. Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run Citavi on Ubuntu using [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

Please notice that not all Citavi versions are (currently) supported by Wine; more info can be found on Wine's official website:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=4895

Comment: I'm working with CITAVI ver. 4. Not suitable for Wine yet. I'll be waiting patiently. Thanks for your reply.